# SQLAlchemy whole model validation with Cerberus

Tags: python, validation, sqlalchemy, cerberus

I want to create some universal validation mechanism for all models using cerberus. The goal is to have cerberus schema in model's `__schema__` property and perform validation of whole model using this schema each time model's state changed (not necessarily before insert or update). I thought about using events but I'm not sure how to do it and do not miss something.

Comment: Based on what you're describing, you might be better off using marshmallow instead of cerberus: http://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#quotes-api-flask-sqlalchemy

Comment: Perfect. That's works for me well! Thank you!

Comment: @dizzyf, how to mark your comment as correct answer?

Comment: I'll paste it as an actual answer... Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you're describing, you might be better off using marshmallow instead of cerberus:

http://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#quotes-api-flask-sqlalchemy